# PHP runs, echo command doesn't render anything

Tags: php, echo

I'm using a php file to send emails using Mandrill. I'm testing it on WAMPServer. All commands on the PHP file run correctly, and the email gets sent. HOWEVER, a simple echo command afterwards does not render anything on the browser! What am I missing?

I've tried adding flush() to the code, and adding implicit_flush = On to php.ini as well, to no avail.

```
...
$message = new Swift_Message($subject);
      $message->setFrom($from);
      $message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
      $message->setTo($to);
      $message->addPart($text, 'text/plain');

      if ($recipients = $swift->send($message, $failures))
      {
        echo "Message successfully sent!";
      }
```

Comment: Do you use the recipients variable

Comment: @GideonAppoh you may want to read the question again.

Comment: Maybe there is an output buffer active?

Comment: Is this script within an HTML tag that has a style applied to it to make the text hidden? Run your script and check the source code from within the web browser.

Comment: @Mike: No. It's a separate PHP file that gets run when a form on client side gets submitted.

Comment: @arkashca I was asking whether `$recipients` is needed somewhere in the scripts if not, Shaahin should run the `$swift->send(a, b)` in a boolean form that `$swift->send(a, b) === true`. 


Also at Shaahin If the HTML file (which contains the PHP file) has some specific body or wrapper styles it can be possible that is echoing the message behind that wrapper. If you want to check that try using developer tools.

Comment: @ShaahinSh Did you check `arkascha` point? If you use any framework `output buffer` may be enabled or maybe you yourself did that before

Comment: @arkashca I'm also suspecting something fishy on client-side page is going on - but Developer Tools console doesn't show anything.

Comment: @Hossein I'm not using any framework.

Comment: try `ob_get_contents` after echo.

Comment: @jigar Didn't make a difference.

Comment: I nailed down the culprit. It's jquery.backstretch.min.js which is a part of my client-side included scripts.